# Medieval gothic font with cyrillic characters

Tags: font-recommendation, blackletter

There are plenty medieval gothic fonts with latin characters, but I can’t find one with cyrillic characters. Can you recommend some?

Comment: To quote Alex Trebek, "Please state your answer in the form of a question". Are you looking for resources for fonts? Ideas for specific fonts? Tutorials for creating fonts?

Comment: That's a fantastic statement. Now where's the question?

Comment: You're right. There aren't a whole lot of them. Here's the small list returned via a myfonts search: http://new.myfonts.com/search/text%3Acyrillic+text%3Ablackletter/fonts/

Answer (score 3):

The Cyrillic alphabet has a somewhat different genealogy from blackletter, although they share some common ancestry. From a typographic standpoint, Cyrillic blackletter seems to me something of an oxymoron, but if you really want to go ahead with it I would say [Blonde Fraktur](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/paratype/blonde-fraktur/), which the designer herself points out isn't really Fraktur and isn't really medieval blackletter (and certainly isn't blonde!), is probably a good choice if you're going to be working with a modern Cyrillic character set.

Comment: +1 for an answer that will provoke more interesting research despite being itself provoked by a poor quality "question".  Looking forward to someday reading *Ruminations from a Gilbertson* with tidbits from all the random corners of the design world...  ;)

Comment: LOL! Ruminations, indeed. I'll have to work on that second stomach... As to the question, non-native English speakers sometimes phrase questions as statements in English. My wife is Italian, and used to do that a lot, so I'm kind of grooved in to the unusual phrasing.

Comment: One flaw with both Moyenage and Blonde Fraktur is that neither include the Yus letters. This is understandable as Polish is the only living Savic language to preserve the nasal vowels and is wirtten with the Roman Alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

The following is compiled from threads on Cyrillic blackletter fonts on [Typografie.info](http://www.typografie.info/3/topic/17237-griechische-und-kyrillische-schriften/), [the Unifraktur board](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/unifraktur-forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1355#p2484) and [Typophile](http://typophile.com/node/101331).

First, here are some digital blackletter fonts containing Cyrillic characters:

- [San Marco](http://www.linotype.com/109280/sanmarcocyrillicroman-font.html)
- [Encient German Gothic](http://www.abstractfonts.com/font/6977)
- [AZ McLeud Normal](http://www.paratype.com/pstore/fonts/AZ-McLeud.htm)
- [Kaas](http://vllg.com/incubator/kaas)
- [Moyenage](http://www.stormtype.com/family-moyenage.html)

In some of the above threads, you can als find references to old specimen containing may cyrillic blackletter fonts. Here are some samples:

[image: Historic Cyrillic blackletter specimen]
[image: Historic Cyrillic blackletter specimen]
[image: Historic Cyrillic blackletter specimen]

Finally, [here](http://vau-ef-be.beepworld.de/galerie1.htm) are some modern-day usages of Cyrillic blackletter fonts.